# Fetching zero cells in XLS file using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl, parsing, xls

First refer to Stack Overflow question *[Using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835021)*.

The data structure looks alike the following:

```
      col1      col2    col3   col4   col5
row1  School    1
row2  Dean      John
row3  No.stu.   55
row4  some irrelevant stuff
row5  School2   2
row6  Dean      Tony
row7  No. stu.  60
row8  some irrelevant stuff
row9  School    3
row10 Dean      James
row11 No.stu.   56
row12 No. teacher 20
row13 School    4
row14 Dean      Tom
row15 No.stu.   79
row16 No. teacher 21
row17 course
row18           math    2
row19           eng     4
row20 teacher   name    age   gender   race
row21           Jane    20    female   white
row22 student   name    Lee
row23           SAT     1434
row24           gender  male
```

The output I would like to achieve is:

```
      col1  col2  col3     col4          col5         col6          col7        col8       col9
row1 School Dean No.stu.  No. teacher  course_math  course_eng  teacher_name  teacher_age  teacher_gender    teacher_race    student_name   student_SAT   student_gender
row2 1      John  55
row3 2      Tony  60
row4 3      James 56       20
row5 4      Tome  79       21              2           4            Jane        20          female                white         Lee         1434          male
```

And thanks to gangabass, the code I have been given is that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

my ($infile) = @ARGV;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse("$Bin/Test.xls");
die $parser->error unless defined $workbook;
my ($worksheet) = $workbook->worksheets();

my %data;
my $row    = 0;
my $school = "";
while (1) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, 0);
    last unless defined($cell);

    my $key = $cell->value();
    my $value = $worksheet->get_cell($row++, 1)->value();

    if ($key eq "School") {

        $school = $value;
        next;
    }

    $data{$school}->{$key} = $value;
}
sleep 1;
```

I start from parsing row17-row19. The first problem I came across was the empty cell in (row17, col3). The code errors out when it arrives here. Knowing that an Excel cell differentiates between 'empty' and 'blank', I can play around with it by setting the cell format of the original XLS file to others except 'general'. However, it is just a temporary solution. I wonder if there are any commands that I could use to fetch the empty cell. I already tried `unformatted()` by adding:

```
my $unformattedvalue = $worksheet->get_cell( $row++, 1 )->unformatted();
```

It, however, does not work out.

I then tried to specify the data structure under 'course' state using the following code:

```
my %data;
my $row    = 0;
my $school = "";
my $course = ""; #Initial value for the state of course
while (1) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, 0);
    last unless defined($cell);

    my $key = $cell->value();
    my $value  = $worksheet->get_cell( $row++, 1 )->value();
    my $value1 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row++, 2 )->value(); #Fetching the value in column 3

    if ($key eq "School") {

        $school = $value;
        next;
    }

    if ($key eq "course") { #Just mimicking the how we construct the structure of 'School'

         $course = $value1;
         next;
    }

    $data{$school}->{$key} = $value;  #Must be something wrong here, but can not figure out
}
```

The code does not go through and gives `Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at xxx line of 'my $value1 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row++, 2 )->value()';`

So in short, my questions are:

1. In general, how do I fetch empty cells in XLS without intervening the process?
2. How do I parse a structure like following by using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

   ```
   row17 course
   row18           math    2
   row19           eng     4
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a `$row++` when you shouldn't be.

Try this code instead as your starting point:

```
my %data;
my $state = "";
my $school = "";
my $student = "";
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my $row = $row_min;
while ($row <= $row_max) {
    my $cell0 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 0 );
    my $cell1 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 );

    if (defined($cell0)) {
        my $key = $cell0->value();
        if ($key eq 'School') {
            $state = 'school';
            $school = $cell1->value();
        } elsif ($key eq 'course') {
            $state = 'course';
        } elsif ($key eq 'teacher') {
            $state = 'teacher';
        } elsif ($key eq 'student') {
            $state = 'student');
            $student = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 2 )->value();
        } else {
            $data{$school}{$key} = $cell1->value();
        }
    } elsif ($state eq 'course') {
        # process columns for course
    } elsif ($state eq 'teacher') {
        # process columns for teacher
    } elsif ($state eq 'student') {
        # process columns for student
    }
    $row++;
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%data);
```

**Update:**

To process the teacher rows, I would first declare a %teacher_columns hash outside the first while loop and also the $col_min and $col_max using the col_range() method. Then inside the `$key eq 'teacher'` elsif clause, I would do something like this:

```
%teacher_columns = (); # clear it out in case column names are different for this school
for my $col (2 .. $col_max) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
    $teacher_columns{$cell->value()} = $col if defined($cell) and $cell->value();
}
```

Then in the `state eq 'teacher'` elsif clause, I would do something like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %teacher_columns) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $teacher_columns{$key});
    if (defined($cell)) {
      # store cell data into proper location of your data hash
    }
}
```

Comment: great thanks to @imran. it works pretty well. But i am a little too stupid to understand the code. with `$teacher_columns{$cell->value()} = $col if defined($cell) and $cell->value(), ` we basically construct a two-layer hash, with the column value as first layer and column number as the second one. My question is that this block will only be triggered while reaching 'teacher' and thus only fetching the cells values related to 'teacher', right? And in  `my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $teacher_columns{$key});` ,how does the `get_cell` method fetch the +1 row value?

Comment: @user2198367 You are approximately right. %teacher_columns is a single level hash that will map the column name like gender to a column number. Yes, this gets re-populated every time we are at the 'teacher' row. About your last question, you do not need to worry about doing +1 on the row, you are already in the 'teacher' state and subsequent rows will be processed as a teacher row until another state is encountered.

Comment: just fixed a typo in the updated answer. The last line where it said `$state eq 'course'` should have been `$state eq 'teacher'`

Comment: great thanks @imran! there is though one minor problem while i  re-write into a new xls file. please see update. cheers..

Comment: Great, Thanks @Imran

Answer (score 0):

Here is my homework:

I was simply adding the process for columns.

```
elsif ($state eq 'student') {
        my $key = $cell1->value();
        $data{$school}{$student}{$key} =$cell2->value();
}  elsif ($state eq 'course') {
       my $key = $cell1->value();
        $data{$school}{$course}{$key} =$cell2->value();
```

where `$cell2` is defined as:

```
my $cell2 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 2 );
```

It gives me:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => {
                   'course' => {
                                 'math' => '2',
                                 'eng' => '4'
                               },
                   'No.Stu' => '79',
                   'No.Teacher' => '21',
                   'Lee' => {
                              'SAT' => '1434',
                              'gender' => 'male'
                            },
                   'Dean' => 'Tom'
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'No.Stu' => '55',
                   'Dean' => 'John'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'No.Stu' => '56',
                   'No.Teacher' => '20',
                   'Dean' => 'James'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'No.Stu' => '60',
                   'Dean' => 'Tony'
                 }
        };
```

which looks good.

But I have no idea about how to process the column for teacher as it has some different structures:

```
        col1      col2    col3   col4   col5
  row20 teacher   name    age   gender   race
  rwo21           Jane    20    female   white
```

I tried to loop over the columns to fetch the cell values as keys but not succeed:

```
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
my $col = $col_min;
my $cell3 = $worksheet->get_cell(++$row, $col );

elsif ($state eq 'teacher') {
        while ($col <= $col_max) {
            my $key = $worksheet->get_cell($row, $col++ );
        }
           $data{$school}{$teacher}{$key} =$cell3->value();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Update: I follow what @imran suggested, and it worked pretty well and then I just rewrite what I have parsed into a new XLS file using the following code:

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

$workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('Result.xls');
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$col = 0;
$row = 0;

$worksheet->write( $row++, $col,
    ["School", "No.Stu", "No.Teacher", "Dean","Course_math", "Course_eng", "student_SAT", "student_name", "student_gender", "teacher_race", "teacher_name", "teacher_age", "teacher_gender"] );

foreach my $school( sort keys %data ) {

     $worksheet->write( $row++, $col,
        [ $school, @{$data{$school}}{ "No.Stu", "No.Teacher", "Dean"}, @{$data{$school}{course}}{ "math", "eng"}, @{$data{$school}{student}}{ "SAT", "name", "gender"}, @{$data{$school}{teacher}}{ "race", "name", "age", "gender"} ]) ;
}

$workbook->close();
```

It all worked well except one minor thing. The cell for `teacher_age` is empty, but it shows in the hash table that it has already been parsed. I can not figure that out...

The hashed teacher part is as follows:

```
           'teacher' => {
                          'race' => 'white',
                          'name' => 'Jane',
                          'age ' => '25',
                          'gender' => ' female'
                        },
```

And the code I used is exactly what you suggested, but the cell for 'teacher_age' in re-formatted xls. file is empty.

Update 2: Back to the question about 'state', does it always start parsing from the subsequent row? What if I have the following data structure:

```
 School    1
 course    math
           eng
 ...
 School     2
 course    phy
 ...
 School     3
 course    chem
           gym
           music
```

If I use the old code and define a course state, I can only parse `eng` from `school 1`, `gym and music` course from `school 2`. Well, I was thinking to define the course state one row ahead but did not get any luck. Any suggestions?

Update:

I followed @imran's suggestion by changing the course code to:

```
} elsif ($key eq 'course') {
            $state = 'course';
            $course = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 )->value();
}
```

And correspondingly the hash table as:

```
} elsif ($state eq 'course') {
            my $key = $cell1->value();
            $data{$school}{$course}{$key} =$cell1->value();
}
```

However, it can only parse

```
 '1' => {
                   'math' => {
                               'eng' => 'eng'
                             },
       }
 '3' => {
   'chem' => {
                               'gym' => 'gym',
                               'music' => 'music
                             },
      }
```

And no parsing for `school2`.

The problem has been solved by using simply proceeding `course` right after it reaches the key. i.e. instead of having separate blocks of defining `course keys` and proceeding the course table. I now have:

```
  } elsif ($key eq 'course') {
            $state = 'course';
            $course = $state;
            my $key = $cell1->value();
            $data{$school}{$course}{$key} = $key;
}
```

And it does that trick. But I am still curious about how it works.

Comment: i will update my answer with a suggestion on how to process the teacher rows shortly.

Comment: you're able to print the race, name and gender data for the teacher but not the age? can you show the teacher part of your hash?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, @imran. i was able to print all the sub-cat for teacher but the cell for age in the new xls file is empty.

Comment: There is a space at the end of 'age '. You can either add the space when you print to the destination excel file or trim the value when you are reading it in the source file.

Comment: @imran, sorry but i have another general question regarding `state`. really appreciated!

Comment: notice how when in  the `} elsif ($key eq 'student') {` section we get the student name? you can read in the course the same way in its if-else clause

Comment: @imran not a perfect parse, maybe i did not do the hash table right.

Comment: course key is in column 2 and value in column 3. you need to put those in your "course" sub-hash.

Comment: hi @imran, please note that `course` now has a lightly different structure from before. Course key is in column1 and value is in column 2. Please see the update above and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: hi @imran, my problem has been solved by proceeding `course` right afte reaching the `$key course`!see updated.

Comment: you are going through the spreadsheet line by line. When you are at the line that has 'course' in the first column, the code `elsif ($key eq 'course')` is true and so you process the remainder of that row.

Comment: oh, so it means `elsif ($key eq 'course')` can handle the stuff in the same row. But why does the original code not work? Is it because when it reaches`elsif ($state eq 'course')` is true, it then automatically start proceeding from the next row? Cheers @imran

Comment: yes. when it reaches `$state eq course` it is on one of the subsequent rows.