# does the 'state' always start parsing from the subsequent row?

Tags: perl, excel, parsing, hash, spreadsheet

The original post is too long: [Fetching zero cells in XLS file using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907022/fetching-zero-cells-in-xls-file-using-spreadsheetparseexcel)

The data structure of the xls. file looks alike the following:

```
      col1      col2    col3   col4   col5 
row1  School    1
row2  Dean      John
row3  No.stu.   55
row4  some irrelevant stuff 
row5  School2   2
row6  Dean      Tony 
row7  No. stu.  60 
row8  some irrelevant stuff
row9  School    3
row10 Dean      James
row11 No.stu.   56
row12 No. teacher 20
row13 School    4
row14 Dean      Tom
row15 No.stu.   79
row16 No. teacher 21
row17 course    
row18           math    2
row19           eng     4      
row20 teacher   name    age   gender   race 
row21           Jane    20    female   white  
row22 student   name    Lee 
row23           SAT     1434
row24           gender  male
```

as imran suggested, i used the following structure using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

```
    my %data;
    my $state = "";
    my $school = "";
    my $student = "";
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my $row = $row_min;
    while ($row <= $row_max) {
        my $cell0 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 0 );
        my $cell1 = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 );

        if (defined($cell0)) {
            my $key = $cell0->value();
            if ($key eq 'School') {
                $state = 'school';
                $school = $cell1->value();
            } elsif ($key eq 'course') {
                $state = 'course';
            } elsif ($key eq 'teacher') {
                $state = 'teacher';
            } elsif ($key eq 'student') {
                $state = 'student');
                $student = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 2 )->value();
            } else {
                $data{$school}{$key} = $cell1->value();
            }
        } elsif ($state eq 'course') {
            # process columns for course
        } elsif ($state eq 'teacher') {
            # process columns for teacher
        } elsif ($state eq 'student') {
            # process columns for student
        }
        $row++;
    }
```

which works pretty well.

But it seems that in each `state`, it start parsing from the second row. Namely, if we claim course as a state and it start processing from the subsequent row until it reaches the next `state`. However, if for example, the course state has a slightly different data structure for each school, namely the key and one of the value for `state` course are in the same row,

```
     School    1 
     course    math    
               eng
     ...
     School     2
     course    phy
     ...   
     School     3 
     course    chem 
               gym 
               music
```

If i stick to the original code using:

```
 } elsif ($key eq 'course') {
                $state = 'course';
                $course = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 )->value();
    }
```

and correspondingly the hash table as:

```
} elsif ($state eq 'course') {
            my $key = $cell1->value();
            $data{$school}{$course}{$key} =$cell1->value();
}
```

however, it can only parse

```
 '1' => {
                   'math' => {
                               'eng' => 'eng'
                             },
       }
'3' => {
   'chem' => {
                               'gym' => 'gym',
                               'music' => 'music
                             },
      }
```

And no parsing for `school2`.

The question is that if there any flexibility of this module which allows me parse from wherever i want to?

Best regards,

Comment: huh??? Your code is the one specifying the location. The module will happily provide you the contents of any cell you want whenever you ask for it.

Comment: yes. @kailash19 that was the structure i want. but somehow i could not make the right hash table. say if i define the row where `course` cell stays as key, i lost the value that is in the same row of course. In this example, i can only parse `eng` from `school 1`, `gym` and `music` for `school 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the structure like below and not the one mentioned above:

```
'1' => {
               'course' => {
                           'math' => 'math'
                           'eng' => 'eng'
                         },
   }
'3' => {
               'course' => {
                           'chem' => 'chem'
                           'gym' => 'gym',
                           'music' => 'music
                         },
  }
```

So, your Hash name should start with the school number and inside have hash of course and inside with key value pair for all courses offered.

This way, you will be able to parse it later very easily too.

**EDIT:**

you can change your code to something like this(i dont know the exact way you doing it):

```
 } elsif ($key eq 'course') {
            $state = 'course';
            $course = $state;
            $key = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 )->value();
            $data{$school}{$course}{$key} = $key;
}
```

Something like this and it should work, you might have to do some changes based on your requirement.